# How do I incorporate $stmt into my search?

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

Right now I have everything set up correctly with my lines of code because my search bar works, however I am trying to add the first chunk of code to my second chunk of code to help prevent sql injection. This has racked my brain, and I feel as though I have hit a brick-wall. Any help would be appreciated.

I am not sure how to incorporate these lines of code...

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT * FROM article WHERE art_country=? OR art_city=?');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $art_country, $art_city);
$stmt->execute();
```

Into this, and make it work...

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM article WHERE art_country LIKE '%$search%' OR art_city LIKE '%$search%'";
if($result = $mysqli->query($sql)) {
    if($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_array()){
        echo " 
        //populate to page code...
    }
    $result->free();
} else {
    echo "No results, search again.";
}

} else {
    echo "ERROR: Could not execute $sql. " .$mysqli->error;
}
```

Thank you

As of right now here is everything I have

```
<?php
        if (isset($_POST['submit-search'])) {
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT * FROM article WHERE art_country LIKE ? OR art_city LIKE ?'); 
        $art_country = '%'.$art_country.'%'; 
        $art_city = '%'.$art_city.'%'; 
        $stmt->bind_param('ss', $art_country, $art_city); 
        if ($stmt->execute()) {
          $result = $stmt->get_result();{ 
            if($result->num_rows > 0) {
              while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 
                echo "
                <div class='article-box'>
                    <a class ='search-link' href='".$row['art_URL']."'>
                    <img class='search-image' src=".$row['art_imageURL'].">
                    </a>
                    <a class ='search-link' href='".$row['art_URL']."'>
                    <h4 class='search-title'>".$row['art_title']."</h4>
                    </a>
                    <a class ='search-link' href='".$row['art_URL']."'>
                    <p class='article-search'>".$row['art_description']."</p>
                    </a>
                    <div class='description-container'>
                    <span><h3 class='index-page'>".$row['art_city']." | ".$row['art_country']." | ".$row['art_date']."</h3></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class='divider'></div>
                </div>";
            }
            $result->free();
        } else {
            echo "No results, search again.";
        }
        } 
    }
}
?>
```

Original and working before mysqli

```
if (isset($_POST['submit-search'])) {
                //mysqli...... prevents people from editing the database
                $search = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['search']);
                //could just be title this seslects everything.
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM article WHERE art_country LIKE '%$search%' OR art_city LIKE '%$search%'"; 

                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                $queryResult = mysqli_num_rows($result);

                if ($queryResult > 0) {
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                      echo "
                        <div class='article-box'>
                          <a class ='search-link' href='".$row['art_URL']."'>
                            <img class='search-image' src=".$row['art_imageURL'].">
                          </a>
                          <a class ='search-link' href='".$row['art_URL']."'>
                            <h4 class='search-title'>".$row['art_title']."</h4>
                          </a>
                          <a class ='search-link' href='".$row['art_URL']."'>
                            <p class='article-search'>".$row['art_description']."</p>
                          </a>
                          <div class='description-container'>
                            <span><h3 class='index-page'>".$row['art_city']." | ".$row['art_country']." | ".$row['art_date']."</h3></span>
                          </div>
                          <div class='divider'></div>
                        </div>";
                      }
                    } else {
                      echo "No results. Search again.";
                    }
                  }
```

Comment: How much variable do you put into bind_param? 2 true? so why you use just 1  "s" ?

Comment: In your working code you use LIKE and not EQUAL is ok?

Comment: Side node: As Simone points out, the two queries you have got here are not actually equivalent to each other.

Comment: Anyway... `$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT * FROM article WHERE art_country LIKE ? OR art_city LIKE ?'); $art_country = '%'.$art_country.'%'; $art_city = '%'.$art_city.'%';
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $art_country, $art_city);
if ($stmt->execute()) { $result = $stmt->get_result(); ...` should start you off down the right road. I have corrected the query and parameters for you.

Comment: @ADyson this is what I got and it seems to work! Thank youvery much
```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT * FROM article WHERE art_country LIKE ? OR art_city LIKE ?'); $art_country = '%'.$art_country.'%'; 
            $art_city = '%'.$art_city.'%'; 
            $stmt->bind_param('ss', $art_country, $art_city); 
            if ($stmt->execute()) { 
                $result = $stmt->get_result();{
                    if($result->num_rows > 0) {
                        while($row = $result->fetch_array()){
                            echo "
```

Comment: @ADyson the code I provided returns all articles, and not the one's explicitly searched for. Can you help me?

Comment: Not easily no, since I can't see your data and I can't see what search terms you are submitting. Provide sample database data, sample input, expected result and actual result, please. Then we can understand the issue.

Comment: P.S. Bear in mind that if you only enter data in one of the fields then inevitably it will return all rows, because the query will end up something like `SELECT * FROM article WHERE art_country LIKE '%xyz%' OR art_city LIKE '%%'`. And of course %% will just cause it to return everything. I don't know if that's your problem (since you didn't provide any data as I mentioned) but it's certainly a possibility. But if the inputs are optional then you need to check if anything was entered in that field before building it into the WHERE clause and the parameter list.

Comment: Each row is an individual article. By typing in a country, or a city the search should return all articles with the art_country, or art_city. As of right now it is returning all articles. 

Thank you for your continued help

Comment: Ok so it's as I described, you need to build the query gradually based on what's actually been submitted

Comment: Here is everything I have, before moving to mysqli my query and code worked like a charm. I'm not sure what needs to be done. Do I have to use older query? I edited initial post with all code.

Comment: Ok. Something occurs to me: Is there one search input field, or two? Because in your new version you have `$art_country` and `$art_city` as two separate variables (and it's not clear how you are populating them), but in your old version you used `$search` only (and it's not clear how that was populated either). So maybe that's your issue? You seem to have change how the query is populated as well as just switching to prepared statements

Comment: There is one search input field which is an input search bar. The user can search Italy, and all articles pertaining to Italy will populate. The user could also search Venice and all articles pertaining to Venice will populate.

Comment: Ok. So please explain how you are populating  $art_country and $art_city when the form is submitted?

Comment: Posted old method that worked, was it the (isset($_POST['submit-search'])) ???

Comment: `isset($_POST['submit-search']` just checks whether a variable called "submit-search" was sent when the form was submitted. it doesn't put any values into any variables. In the original code you are doing `$search =... $_POST["search"];`. In the new version you removed this, for no obvious reason, and replaced it with $art_country and $art_city, which don't actually exist or have any real values in them. I have no idea why you did this. I wonder if you don't entirely understand how PHP and HTML forms work together? Otherwise you'd know that this line of code was very important.

Comment: I don't fully know, I am piecing it together...

Comment: I see. If you didn't understand the basics, maybe you should have taken a HTML forms + PHP tutorial before attempting this change, then you have had a clearer understanding of what all the different bits of the code were actually doing, and whether they were important.

Comment: Try it like this: `if (isset($_POST['submit-search'])) {
        $search = $_POST["search"];
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT * FROM article WHERE art_country LIKE ? OR art_city LIKE ?'); 
        $search = '%'.$search.'%'; 
        $stmt->bind_param('ss', $search, $search);` (You don't need the mysqli_real_escape_string bit now that you're using parameters, in case you're wondering).

Comment: Thank you, I'm trying to learn as I go, and I had an older version working, only then to come across SQL injection. Then had to start over and what I had pieced together no longer was working. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the discussion in the comments, this should be the final version you need.

Summary of changes:

- Re-instate the `$search` variable, which gets data from `$_POST` and then is passed as the parameter value for both parameters
- re-instate the use of `LIKE` in your query, to make the query equivalent to the one in your old code
- add an extra `s` in the first argument to `bind_param`, as you have 2 parameters rather than 1
- Replace `if($result = $mysqli->query($sql)) {` with `if ($stmt->execute()) {` so it checks whether the query succeeds
- Use `get_result()` to retrieve the result object from the executed statement.

After that, your code can proceed as it already did.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit-search'])) {
  $search = $_POST["search"];         
  $stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT * FROM article WHERE art_country LIKE ? OR art_city LIKE ?');          
  $search = '%'.$search.'%';          
  $stmt->bind_param('ss', $search, $search); 

  if ($stmt->execute()) {
      $result = $stmt->get_result();
 
      if($result->num_rows > 0) {

          while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 
              echo "
              <div class='article-box'>
                <a class ='search-link' href='".$row['art_URL']."'>
                <img class='search-image' src=".$row['art_imageURL'].">
                </a>
                <a class ='search-link' href='".$row['art_URL']."'>
                <h4 class='search-title'>".$row['art_title']."</h4>
                </a>
                <a class ='search-link' href='".$row['art_URL']."'>
                <p class='article-search'>".$row['art_description']."</p>
                </a>
                <div class='description-container'>
                <span><h3 class='index-page'>".$row['art_city']." | ".$row['art_country']." | ".$row['art_date']."</h3></span>
                </div>
                <div class='divider'></div>
              </div>";
          }

          $result->free();
      } else {
          echo "No results, search again.";
      }
  } 
} 
?>
```

Comment: Any explanation? What have you changed?

Comment: No, I am asking about the answer. Comments will be deleted. Please add some explanation so that I can understand what you are trying to teach me.

Comment: @Dharman Comments are rarely deleted in my experience. But I'll add a summary.